# Linux to Windows in CLI with Python

Tags: python, linux, command-line-interface, windows-server

I recently discovered PyWinRM module which enables me, from a Linux machine, to establish a session with a 2008/2012 Server machine and then send DOS cmds, cmdlets and scripts to be executed remotely, collecting data and working with.

Example of PyWinRm usage:

```
# Establishing session
s = winrm.Session('server',auth=('user','password'),transport='ntlm')
# Script and run
script="""dir"""
r = s.run_cmd(script)
```

I have now, to find another solution, because my boss wants me to do the same, but with some 2000 and 2003 Servers machines (yeah, 2000 still exists for the moment in certain corporates).

I looked over the internet and the main reason, I think, is the absence of WinRM in earlier version of Win Server.

Which solutions would you suggest, provided that I can't install anything but python modules ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627485/running-commands-on-remote-windows-machine-with-python

Comment: Thanks @Wyrmwood, but I tried all solutions, it does not work.